# How can I obtain a string with spaces from System.in?

Tags: java, string, input

I have this program I'm messing with as I learn Java:

```
package com.nathan2055.booksamples;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Nathan2055
 */
public class Copycat {

    private static Scanner keyboard;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        out.println("This program will copy whatever you type.");
        out.println("Please enter a phrase:");

        String inputPhrase = keyboard.next();
        out.println();
        out.println(inputPhrase);
    }

}
```

But there's a problem. If you run it and enter a phrase with spaces in it, it will only save the string up to the space. How can I get it to save the entire string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()` method returns the space delimeted strings, if you want to get whole line use `nextLine` instead of just `next()`.

```
public class Tester {

private static Scanner keyboard;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    out.println("This program will copy whatever you type.");
    out.println("Please enter a phrase:");

    String inputPhrase = keyboard.nextLine();
    out.println();
    out.println(inputPhrase);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Use nextLine() instead of next()

Answer (score 0):

Use buffered reader instead.

```
BufferedReader reader =
new BufferedReader
(new
InputStreamReader
(System.in));
String input = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(input);
```